# Taking derivative of simple equation with different variable substitution gives differing results?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have a simple equation $$y=a^2b^3$$ with $x=a^2b$. If I substitute $x$ into $y$, I get $$y=xb^2$$
Then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=b^2$$
However, if I want to use $x^2=a^4b^2$ and sub into $y$, I have $$y=a^4b^2\frac{b}{a^2}=x^2\frac{b}{a^2}$$
Now if I differentiate again, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2b}{a^2}x=\frac{2b}{a^2}a^2b=2b^2$$
Why do the two $\frac{dy}{dx}$ differ by 2 when the starting equation is the same? Am I missing something really simple here?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ constants? If so, then $x$ is also a constant.

Comment: @xxxx036 yes they are not a function of anything else

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are constants then $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$. If not, you need to apply the chain rule and product rule.

Comment: @Paul thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are constants, then $x=a^2b$ is also a constant, so calculating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ makes no sense (i.e., it makes as much sense as calculating $\frac{dy}{d3}$, which is none).

If they are new variables, then you need to be careful to see which variable depends on which other variable, and use the chain rule to get your derivatives. In particular,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} \cdot\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial y}{\partial b} \cdot\frac{\partial b}{\partial x} $$

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Brend Don't forget to accept the answer if it is what you needed.

Comment: oops sorry! This is my first time using this website. Thanks for the reminder.